# How to take a date from the next instead of current record if certain condition is true?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Reg_id     package_desc     product_type_desc     term_start_date     term_end_date

FH157377   CC               trail                 16-FEB-15           15-FEB-16  
FH157377   CC               goodwill              16-FEB-16           15-MAR-16  
FH157377   CC               paid                  16-mar-16           15-dec-16  
FH157377   RUM              trail                 20-mar-14           20-aug-14  
FH157377   RUM              paid                  21-aug-14           20-aug-15  
FH157377   RUM              goodwill              21-aug-15           20-dec-15  
FH157377   RUM              paid                  21-dec-15           20-aug-16  
FH157377   RUM              goodwill              21-aug-16           20-nov-16  
FH157377   BGM              goodwill              21-dec-12           20-aug-13  
FH157377   BGM              paid                  21-aug-13            20-nov-16
```

The output I need is that if a 'Goodwill' record follows a 'Trial' product then treat this as 'Trial'.

If a 'Goodwill' record follows a 'Paid' product then treat this as 'Paid'. The *term_end_date* needs to be taken from that 'Goodwill' record too.

The output should be like this:

```
Reg_id     package_desc     product_type_desc     term_start_date     term_end_date

FH157377   CC               trail                  16-FEB-15          15-MAR-16  
FH157377   CC               paid                   16-mar-16          15-dec-16  
FH157377   RUM              trail                  20-mar-14          20-aug-14  
FH157377   RUM              paid                   21-aug-14          20-dec-15  
FH157377   RUM              paid                   21-dec-15          20-nov-16
FH157377   BGM              trail                  21-dec-12          20-aug-13  
FH157377   BGM              paid                   20-aug-13          20-nov-16
```

Comment: What is an "O/p"?  Your question is not clear.  What do you mean by "follows?"  By date?

Comment: Hi oldProgrammer - O/P means the Output. Yes right, if it follows by date per each reg_id.

Comment: I don't think I still totally understand the logic, but most likely, you will need to use oracle analytic functions with windowing.  Google that for some examples.

Comment: Hi Old Programmer - Basically we  need to merge the goodwill records into trail or paid record and update the term_end_date for the trail or paid record with the goodwill term_end_date. :). Please kindly let me know if you still didn't understand my question, so that I will elaborate. :)

Comment: Hi Old Programmer - please kindly let me know if still have any more questions on my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`lead` window function](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions#lead) to inspect the next record and decide to take its term end date:

```
select *
from   (select reg_id,
               package_desc,
               case when product_type_desc = 'goodwill'
                    and  row_number()
                      over (partition by reg_id, package_desc order by term_start_date) = 1
               then 'trail'
               else product_type_desc
               end as product_type_desc,
               term_start_date,
               case lead(product_type_desc, 1) 
                      over (partition by reg_id, package_desc order by term_start_date)
               when 'goodwill' then
                   lead(term_end_date, 1) 
                       over (partition by reg_id, package_desc order by term_start_date)
               else
                   term_end_date
               end  term_end_date
        from   mytable)
where   product_type_desc <> 'goodwill'
```

Output for the sample data:

```
 REG_ID  | PACKAGE_DESC | PRODUCT_TYPE_DESC | TERM_START_DATE | TERM_END_DATE
---------+--------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------
FH157377 |     BGM      |       trail       |   21.12.2012    |   20.08.2013
FH157377 |     BGM      |       paid        |   21.08.2013    |   20.11.2016
FH157377 |     CC       |       trail       |   02/16/2015    |   03/15/2016
FH157377 |     CC       |       paid        |   03/16/2016    |   12/15/2016
FH157377 |     RUM      |       trail       |   03/20/2014    |   08/20/2014
FH157377 |     RUM      |       paid        |   08/21/2014    |   12/20/2015
FH157377 |     RUM      |       paid        |   12/21/2015    |   11/20/2016
```

Comment: Hi Trinicot - It works really great. Thanks for your help. Actually I have missed another requirement in my earlier email. Per suppose if I have another 2 records like                                                                FH157377 | BGM | goodwill | 03/16/2015 | 12/15/2016            FH157377| BGM | PAID | 12/17/2016 | 12/16/2017, then we need to have Goodwill assigned to Trail and Paid should be kept as it is. Right now the goodwill is being assigned to paid although the goodwill comes before the paid.

Comment: Any one please help.

Comment: I updated the query to make sure a first 'goodwill' record (within its partition of same product and package) is not deleted from the result set.

Comment: Hi Trinicot, Sorry if my statement confused you. Actually the Goodwill record should be assigned to Trail and Goodwill start and end date should be assigned to Trail. Basically, its like if there is only one Goodwill before the Paid, it should be assigned to Trail. This table should only contains Trail and Paid records and goodwill after trail --> trail, goodwill agter paid --> paid and only goodwill without trail or paid, assign it to trail with goodwill start_date and end_date.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with *should be assigned to*. Can you explain this is record terms? You want the goodwill record to be displayed, but its *product_type_desc* to be replaced with "trail" when it is the first record and cannot be matched with anything before it? Can you please edit your question and phrase this requirement with sample data and expected outcome?

Comment: Hello Sir, I have edited the question with 2 more BGM records added in the end. I want the goodwill record to be displayed, but its product_type_desc to be replaced with "trail" when it is the first record and cannot be matched with anything before it. Thanks alot for your help on this.

Comment: I have also updated the output generated, based on the extended sample data in your question. Note that the new records appear at the start, because the result is sorted by Oracle like that. I suppose it is not difficult for you to add an `order by` to get it in the sort order you like.

Comment: Hi Trinicot, Actually my requirement has been changed a bit on this and it become more complex too :(. Do you want me to create a new question or just update the existing one?.

Comment: It would indeed be better to ask a new question. If you let me know, I could have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks much Trinicot. I will post the question in another 10 minutes and post the link here.

Comment: Hi Trinicot, MY new question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38605188/oracle-sql-how-to-adjust-the-dates-and-distinct-records-based-on-a-column