# How to adjust the dates and distinct records based on a column

Tags: sql, oracle

```
REG_ID| EVENT_TYPE_CD    | EVENT_DATE | PACKAGE_DESC    |PRODUCT_TYPE|TERM_START_DATE|TERM_END_DATE  
------|------------------|------------|-----------------|------------|---------------|----------  

11156 | NEW SUBSCRIPTION |  23-FEB-16 | CONNECTED CARE  |PAID        | 23-FEB-16     | 23-FEB-16  
11156 | CANCELLATION     |  23-FEB-16 | CONNECTED CARE  |PAID        | 23-FEB-16     | 23-FEB-16  
11156 | UPSELL           |  23-FEB-16 | CONNECTED CARE  |GOODWILL    | 23-FEB-16     | 22-MAR-16  
11156 | CANCELLATION     |  11-MAR-16 | CONNECTED CARE  |GOODWILL    | 23-FEB-16     | 11-MAR-16  
11156 | UPSELL           |  14-MAR-16 | CONNECTED CARE  |GOODWILL    | 14-APR-16     | 13-APR-17  
11156 | EXPIRATION       |  14-APR-16 | CONNECTED CARE  |GOODWILL    | 14-MAR-16     | 13-APR-17  
11163 | UPSELL           |  23-FEB-16 | CONNECTED CARE  |PAID        | 23-FEB-16     | 23-FEB-16  
11163 | CANCELLATION     |  23-FEB-16 | CONNECTED CARE  |PAID        | 23-FEB-16     | 22-MAR-16    
17215 | NEW SUBSCRIPTION |  18-JAN-16 | CONNECTED CARE  |TRIAL       | 18-JAN-16     | 17-JAN-17  
17215 | NEW SUBSCRIPTION |  18-JAN-16 | GUIDANCE        |TRIAL       | 18-JAN-16     | 17-APR-16  
17215 | CANCELLATION     |  22-FEB-16 | GUIDANCE        |TRIAL       | 18-JAN-16     | 22-FEB-16  
17215 | UPSELL           |  25-FEB-16 | GUIDANCE        |GOODWILL    | 25-FEB-16     | 24-APR-16  
17215 | EXPIRATION       |  25-APR-16 | GUIDANCE        |GOODWILL    | 25-FEB-16     | 24-APR-16  
17215 | NEW SUBSCRIPTION |  18-JAN-16 | REMOTE          |TRIAL       | 18-JAN-16     | 17-APR-16  
17215 | UPSELL           |  25-FEB-16 | REMOTE          |GOODWILL    | 25-FEB-16     | 24-APR-16  
17215 | NEW SUBSCRIPTION |  18-JUN-16 | REMOTE          |PAID        | 18-JUN-16     | 17-JUL-16  
17215 | UPSELL           |  25-JUL-16 | REMOTE          |GOODWILL    | 25-JUL-16     | 24-AUG-16
```

The output I need is that everything needs to be sorted by EVENT_DATE (Series of Events)

1. if a 'Goodwill' EVENT_DATE follows a 'Trial' product EVENT_DATE
   then treat this as 'Trial'. If a 'Goodwill' EVENT_DATE follows a
   'Paid' product EVENT_DATE then treat this as 'Paid' and adjust the
   TERM_END_DATE (Example for REMOTE Ideal scenario when there is no
   Cancellation or EXPIRATION event_type_cd for particular PACKAGE_DESC
   in a REG_ID)
2. If there is a Event After the Cancellation then ignore Cancellation (11163 shows up: that's the reason since there is no new
   event after the cancellation)
3. If there are multiple Goodwill's
   following the trail we need to take the maximum TERM_END_DATE in the
   cycle needs to assigned as TERM_END_DATE (REG_ID 17215 and GUIDANCE).
4. EXPIRATION RECORD should always be there and its term_start_date
   needs to get adjusted to the Term_start_date of the Cycle's 1st
   record.

```
REG_ID| EVENT_TYPE_CD    | EVENT_DATE | PACKAGE_DESC    |PRODUCT_TYPE|TERM_START_DATE| TERM_END_DATE  
------|------------------|------------|-----------------|------------|---------------|----------  

11156 | NEW SUBSCRIPTION |  23-FEB-16 | CONNECTED CARE  |PAID        | 23-FEB-16     | 13-APR-17  
11156 | EXPIRATION       |  14-APR-16 | CONNECTED CARE  |PAID        | 23-FEB-16     | 13-APR-17  
11163 | UPSELL           |  23-FEB-16 | CONNECTED CARE  |PAID        | 23-FEB-16     | 23-FEB-16  
11163 | CANCELLATION     |  23-FEB-16 | CONNECTED CARE  |PAID        | 23-FEB-16     | 22-MAR-16  
17215 | NEW SUBSCRIPTION |  18-JAN-16 | CONNECTED CARE  |TRIAL       | 18-JAN-16     | 17-JAN-17  
17215 | NEW SUBSCRIPTION |  18-JAN-16 | GUIDANCE        |TRIAL       | 18-JAN-16     | 24-APR-16  
17215 | EXPIRATION       |  25-APR-16 | GUIDANCE        |TRAIL       | 18-JAN-16     | 24-APR-16  
17215 | NEW SUBSCRIPTION |  18-JAN-16 | REMOTE          |TRIAL       | 18-JAN-16     | 24-APR-16  
17215 | NEW SUBSCRIPTION |  18-JUN-16 | REMOTE          |PAID        | 18-JUN-16     | 24-AUG-16
```

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name --> Thanks for editing my question for better understanding.. :)

Comment: I have edited my question for better understanding. Thanks all for your help in advance once again.

Comment: I am trying to figure out the sort order of the final result. From to table your provided, it seems to be `reg_id, package_desc, event_date`, except that the `reg_id` is not sorted well in your table: it goes down and up again. Also, there are still ambiguous cases, like the last two lines in the final table. How are they ordered? Is it based on the last two columns? like: `reg_id, package_desc, event_date, term_start_date, term_end_date`?

Comment: Continuing about order: there is something missing in the original table. Why are the first three records for `reg_id = 11156` ordered as they are? They have the same `package_desc=CONNECTED CARE`, the same `event_date=23-FEB-16`, the same `term_start_date=23-FEB-16`, and the `term_end_date` is different, but not sorted by... There should be a way to identify the sort order.

Comment: Hi Trinicot - The Sort Order should be only on Reg_id, Package_desc, event_date. For each package in a particular reg_id, We just needs to assign the LAST EVENT_DATE's term_end_date to the term_end_date of the Paid or Trial product.

Comment: But how do you order when those three fields have the same value? The order is important, because it affects how the rules are applied (*" if ... follows ... then ...*"). So how do you order when the 3 are equal?

Comment: Hi Trinicot, If those three fields have the same value, We need to assign the max(term_end_date) of the goodwill record. In some scenarios a Customer can buy a product for 2 years and immediately cancel it. After Cancellation the company that offers the product Can call him and offer a Goodwill(free) access to the product for some time(Max of 1 year). While we are merging the record we need to apply the business rule that TERM_END_DATE Should be of Goodwill's term_end_date.

Comment: Sorry Trinicot, If my explanation doesn't makes any sense. Please let me know if you have any further doubts. I will try to explain it clearly.

Comment: The explanation is useful, but does not answer my question. Be aware that the interpretation of the words "follows", "following", "after", "1st" in your 4 rules is only possible, if you define a UNIQUE way to order records. If possible, add a column to your data that defines the order in case the 3 fields are equal, or provide another way to unambiguously determine the order. I cannot solve this question without that.

Comment: Hi Trinicot, I have just talked to business and unique way to order these records are based on Reg_id, Package_desc, event_date, Term_end_date. I have changed the Source table and term_end_date is updated for reg_id = 11156. It looks like a data issue.  Sorry for that :(

Comment: Still for reg id 11156 the first two records have the same 4 fields: how can I know that the one comes before the other and not the other way round? Also, like I said above: in both tables the sort order is not by reg_id, because 17215  should then be last.

Comment: Hi Trinicot, These 4 fields will get duplicated only when we have a cancellation or Expiration record. The EVENT_TYPE_CD's for Cancellation or Expiration will always follow the New Subscription or UPSELL  for a particular REG_ID, PACKAGE_DESC and not the other way around. I will change the Sort Order for REG_ID now.

Comment: Hi Trinicot, Please kindly let me know if you need any other information from my side. Sorry for troubling you these many times. You have been more than helpful and I must appreciate a lot for your help. I have been working around this too and not able to come up with any query :(

Comment: I am working on your question. I will come back to you.

Comment: What should happen if the first record in a cycle is 'GOODWILL': should it stay? Should it change?

Comment: Hi Trinicot, It should be changed to Trail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules are quite extensive, and your might get better results and performance with PL/SQL code, as that can use variables while iterating over a cursor.

Still, I think the following query may do what you need:

```
select  reg_id, 
        event_type_cd,
        event_date,
        package_desc,
        case product_type when 'GOODWILL' then coalesce(prev_product_type, 'TRIAL')
            else product_type
        end as product_type,
        case event_type_cd when 'EXPIRATION' then first_term_start_date
            else term_start_date
        end as term_start_date,
        case next_product_type when 'GOODWILL' then next_term_end_date
            else term_end_date
        end as term_end_date
from    (select reg_id, 
                event_type_cd,
                event_date,
                package_desc,
                product_type,
                term_start_date,
                term_end_date,
                first_value(term_start_date) over (
                    partition by reg_id, package_desc 
                    order by event_date, term_end_date, event_type_cd desc) as first_term_start_date,
                lead(term_end_date, 1) over (
                    partition by reg_id, package_desc 
                    order by event_date, term_end_date, event_type_cd desc) as next_term_end_date,
                lag(product_type, 1) over (
                    partition by reg_id, package_desc 
                    order by event_date, term_end_date, event_type_cd desc) as prev_product_type,
                lead(product_type, 1) over (
                    partition by reg_id, package_desc 
                    order by event_date, term_end_date, event_type_cd desc) as next_product_type
        from    (select reg_id, 
                        event_type_cd,
                        event_date,
                        package_desc,
                        product_type,
                        term_start_date,
                        term_end_date,
                        lead(product_type, 1, '-') over (
                            partition by reg_id, package_desc 
                            order by event_date, term_end_date, event_type_cd desc) as next_product_type
                from    mytable)
                where   not (event_type_cd = 'CANCELLATION' and next_product_type <> '-')
                and     not (product_type = 'GOODWILL' and next_product_type = 'GOODWILL')
                )
where    not (    product_type = 'GOODWILL' 
              and event_type_cd not in ('EXPIRATION', 'CANCELLATION') 
              and prev_product_type is not null)
order by reg_id, package_desc, event_date, term_end_date, event_type_cd desc
```

The query has a two-level nested sub query.

The **inner-most query** only serves to get the *product_type* of the next record within the cycle (i.e. within the same partition of *reg_id* and *package_desc*).

The **middle query** uses that information to eliminate:

- 'CANCELLATION' records, unless they are the very last record of their cycle;
- Consecutive 'GOODWILL' records, leaving only the last in place of every sequence -- this is last one is temporary, but is at this stage still needed;

The middle query also re-fetches the *product_type* of the next record in the cycle, as it might now have changed due to the eliminated records. Additionally, it determines:

- the *term_start_date* of the first record in the cycle;
- the *term_end_date* of the next record in the cycle;
- the *product_type* of the previous record in the cycle;

Finally, the **outer query** uses this information to:

- set the *product_type* to that of the previous record (or 'TRIAL' if there is no previous) if it concerns a 'GOODWILL' record;
- set the *term_start_date* to the that of the first record in the cycle, if it concerns an 'EXPIRATION' record;
- set the *term_end_date* to that of the next record in the cycle, if the next record concerns a 'GOODWILL' record.

The 'GOODWILL' records (before the change in the first bullet above) are excluded from the result, except when they relate to a first record in their cycle, or correspond to an 'EXPIRATION' or 'CANCELLATION' record.

The `order by` clause uses the order as you mentioned in comments, with an additional `event_type_cd desc` to make sure *"The EVENT_TYPE_CD's for Cancellation or Expiration will always follow the New Subscription or UPSELL for a particular REG_ID, PACKAGE_DESC"*. This is because by fortune both 'NEW SUBSCRIPTION' and 'UPSELL' come both later in the alphabetical order than 'CANCELLATION' and 'EXPIRATION', so in descending order we get them sorted right.

Comment: Hi Trincot, It works like a charm. It gave me the desired output as I need for 3 reg_id's I have tested. Thank you so much. Once again I don't have words to thank you for all your effort. :)

Comment: Hi Trincot, I thought of not disturbing you since you have helped me a lot until now. I have posted another question yesterday and it looks like there are -ve votes on my question, so no response. Would you be able to see if I am missing something in my question and help me on that Scenario. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627219/how-to-delete-the-records-based-upon-prev-and-next-rows-and-assign-the-date-base

Comment: I will have a look. One thing people on StackOverflow do not like is when you ask a question and don't show the code you have tried with. You should always add a paragraph like *"I tried with this SQL ..... but it does not give me the expected result. What am I doing wrong?"* That will lead to fewer down-votes. It is important that you show you have done an effort, and are not just asking the community to do the work for you :) But I will first update your question with better phrasing and formatting. Then you should add such a paragraph.

Comment: I updated your question, which I think is now clearer. Please check if it still reflects what you want. Then add a paragraph "This is what I tried ... etc."

Comment: Hi Trinicot, I have added my query too and the question reflects exactly what I want.

Comment: @ trincot , I only see one issue with the above query though. one of the requirement is to keep the cancellation record if it's last record of the cycle. If a record is of EVENT_TYPE_CD Cancellation and Product_type is Goodwill and also if it's last record of the cycle we are deleting it instead of  keeping it :)

Comment: For that you can just adapt the final `where` clause, and change `<> 'EXPIRATION'` to `not in ('EXPIRATION', 'CANCELLATION')`. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks so much Trincot. :)

Comment: @ Trincot, I have one small change in the requirement. Right now we are populating the TERM_END_DATE for the Trail or Paid with the Last Goodwill Record Term_end_date in the cycle. But I need to populate TERM_END_DATE for the Trail or Paid with the last goodwill record which is not of EXPIRATION or CANCELLATION. Is there a way to do that simply by adjusting this query. Please help. :)

Comment: That is not a trivial change, all the more because you now say *"with the last Goodwill  record term_end_date in the cycle"*. It was not like that in the first place: it took the *following* goodwill records (without interruption) for retrieving the term_end_date, not the *last* (according to rule 3). This change really hits the heart of this query, and deserves a new question. I will be on holidays for the coming ten days, so I am not even sure I can have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks Trincot. Enjoy your holidays and have a safe one :)