# How to Delete the records based upon Prev and Next rows and assign the date based upon certain conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my insert Statements for the Source data.

```
REM INSERTING into EXPORT_TABLE  
SET DEFINE OFF;  
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE   values ('4VKMH','GUIDFREE','UPSELL',to_date('11-MAR-14 17:05:35','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('11-MAR-14 00:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('11-JUN-14 23:59:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),92,0);  
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE   values ('4VKMH','GUIDPAID','UPSELL',to_date('11-MAR-14 17:05:35','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('12-JUN-14 00:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('10-MAR-15 23:59:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),271,73.78);  
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE   values ('4VKMH','GUIDFREE','EXPIRATION',to_date('12-JUN-14 01:26:26','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('11-MAR-14 00:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('11-JUN-14 23:59:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),92,0);  
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE   values ('4VKMH','GUIDPAID','RENEWAL',to_date('11-MAR-15 01:23:01','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('11-MAR-15 00:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('10-MAR-16 23:59:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),365,99);  
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE   values ('4VKMH','GUIDPAID','CANCELLATION',to_date('11-MAR-15 03:11:09','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('11-MAR-15 00:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('11-MAR-15 23:59:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),0,-99);  
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE   values ('4VKMH','GUIDPAID','UPSELL',to_date('16-MAR-15 10:49:34','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('16-MAR-15 00:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('10-MAR-16 23:59:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),360,97.92);  
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE   values ('4VKMH','GUIDPAID','CANCELLATION',to_date('22-FEB-16 18:19:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('16-MAR-15 00:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('22-FEB-16 23:59:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),343,-4.61);  
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE   values ('4VKMH','GUIDPAID','NEW SUBSCRIPTION',to_date('23-FEB-16 13:08:05','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('23-FEB-16 00:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('22-FEB-18 23:59:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),730,178);    
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE   values ('4VKMH','GUIDPAID','CANCELLATION',to_date('23-FEB-16 15:16:44','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('23-FEB-16 00:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('23-FEB-16 23:59:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),0,-178);  
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE   values ('4VKMH','GUIDGWA','UPSELL',to_date('23-FEB-16 15:22:42','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('23-FEB-16 00:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('22-MAR-16 23:59:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),28,0);  
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE   values ('4VKMH','GUIDGWA','CANCELLATION',to_date('11-MAR-16 04:25:50','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('23-FEB-16 00:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('11-MAR-16 23:59:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),17,0);  
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE   values ('4VKMH','GUIDPAID','UPSELL',to_date('14-MAR-16 10:02:05','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('14-MAR-16 00:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('13-APR-16 23:59:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),30,8.41);  
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE   values ('4VKMH','GUIDPAID','UPSELL',to_date('11-APR-16 09:33:06','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('14-APR-16 00:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),to_date('13-MAR-17 23:59:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'),333,90.59);
```

I have my source data as

```
REG_ID  | PRODUCT_CD | EVENT_TYPE      | EVENT_DATE         | TERM_START_DATE    | TERM_END_DATE      | DAYS | AMT
--------+------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------+--------
4VKMH   | GUIDFREE   | UPSELL          | 11-MAR-14 17:05:35 | 11-MAR-14 00:00:00 | 11-JUN-14 23:59:00 |  92  |    0  
4VKMH   | GUIDPAID   | UPSELL          | 11-MAR-14 17:05:35 | 12-JUN-14 00:00:00 | 10-MAR-15 23:59:00 | 271  |   73.78  
4VKMH   | GUIDFREE   | EXPIRATION      | 12-JUN-14 01:26:26 | 11-MAR-14 00:00:00 | 11-JUN-14 23:59:00 |  92  |    0  
4VKMH   | GUIDPAID   | RENEWAL         | 11-MAR-15 01:23:01 | 11-MAR-15 00:00:00 | 10-MAR-16 23:59:00 | 365  |   99     *
4VKMH   | GUIDPAID   | CANCELLATION    | 11-MAR-15 03:11:09 | 11-MAR-15 00:00:00 | 11-MAR-15 23:59:00 |   0  |  -99  
4VKMH   | GUIDPAID   | UPSELL          | 16-MAR-15 10:49:34 | 16-MAR-15 00:00:00 | 10-MAR-16 23:59:00 | 360  |   97.92  
4VKMH   | GUIDPAID   | CANCELLATION    | 22-FEB-16 18:19:00 | 16-MAR-15 00:00:00 | 22-FEB-16 23:59:00 | 343  |   -4.61   
4VKMH   | GUIDPAID   | NEW SUBSCRIPTION| 23-FEB-16 13:08:05 | 23-FEB-16 00:00:00 | 22-FEB-18 23:59:00 | 730  |  178  
4VKMH   | GUIDPAID   | CANCELLATION    | 23-FEB-16 15:16:44 | 23-FEB-16 00:00:00 | 23-FEB-16 23:59:00 |   0  | -178  
4VKMH   | GUIDGWA    | UPSELL          | 23-FEB-16 15:22:42 | 23-FEB-16 00:00:00 | 22-MAR-16 23:59:00 |  28  |    0  
4VKMH   | GUIDGWA    | CANCELLATION    | 11-MAR-16 04:25:50 | 23-FEB-16 00:00:00 | 11-MAR-16 23:59:00 |  17  |    0  
4VKMH   | GUIDPAID   | UPSELL          | 14-MAR-16 10:02:05 | 14-MAR-16 00:00:00 | 13-APR-16 23:59:00 |  30  |    8.41  
4VKMH   | GUIDPAID   | UPSELL          | 11-APR-16 09:33:06 | 14-APR-16 00:00:00 | 13-MAR-17 23:59:00 | 333  |   90.59
```

This data is already sorted by `REG_ID`, `EVENT_DATE`, and `TERM_START_DATE`.

I am trying to generate this output from that:

```
REG_ID  | PRODUCT_CD | EVENT_TYPE      | EVENT_DATE         | TERM_START_DATE    | TERM_END_DATE      | DAYS | AMT
--------+------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------+--------
4VKMH   | GUIDFREE   | UPSELL          | 11-MAR-14 17:05:35 | 11-MAR-14 00:00:00 | 11-JUN-14 23:59:00 |  92  |    0  
4VKMH   | GUIDPAID   | UPSELL          | 11-MAR-14 17:05:35 | 12-JUN-14 00:00:00 | 10-MAR-15 23:59:00 | 271  |   73.78  
4VKMH   | GUIDFREE   | EXPIRATION      | 12-JUN-14 01:26:26 | 11-MAR-14 00:00:00 | 11-JUN-14 23:59:00 |  92  |    0  
4VKMH   | GUIDPAID   | UPSELL          | 16-MAR-15 10:49:34 | 16-MAR-15 00:00:00 | 22-FEB-16 23:59:00 | 360  |   97.92  
4VKMH   | GUIDPAID   | CANCELLATION    | 22-FEB-16 18:19:00 | 16-MAR-15 00:00:00 | 22-FEB-16 23:59:00 | 343  |   -4.61  
4VKMH   | GUIDGWA    | UPSELL          | 23-FEB-16 15:22:42 | 23-FEB-16 00:00:00 | 11-MAR-16 23:59:00 |  28  |    0  
4VKMH   | GUIDGWA    | CANCELLATION    | 11-MAR-16 04:25:50 | 23-FEB-16 00:00:00 | 11-MAR-16 23:59:00 |  17  |    0  
4VKMH   | GUIDPAID   | UPSELL          | 14-MAR-16 10:02:05 | 14-MAR-16 00:00:00 | 13-APR-16 23:59:00 |  30  |    8.41  
4VKMH   | GUIDPAID   | UPSELL          | 11-APR-16 09:33:06 | 14-APR-16 00:00:00 | 13-MAR-17 23:59:00 | 333  |   90.59
```

This is the logic by which the result is derived from the original data:

For each record **A** with `EVENT_TYPE` `'RENEWAL'`, `'UPSELL'`, or `'NEW SUBSCRIPTION'`: if the following record **B** has `EVENT_TYPE` `'CANCELLATION'`, then:

1. if record **B** has the same `EVENT_DATE` date part as **A** (ignore time), eliminate both record **A** and **B** from the result. So this is why records 4, 5, 8 and 9 are eliminated;
2. else if record **B** has an earlier `TERM_END_DATE` value than record **A**, update **A**'s `TERM_END_DATE` to that of **B**. So this is why record 10 has an updated `TERM_END_DATE`

I have tried to handle my 1st condition using the Following SQL and getting a issue ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

```
         (SELECT REG_ID, 
            EVENT_TYPE,
            EVENT_DATE,
            PRODUCT_CD,
            TERM_START_DATE,
            TERM_END_DATE,
            LAG(EVENT_TYPE, 1, '-') over (
                        PARTITION BY REG_ID, PRODUCT_CD
                        ORDER BY EVENT_DATE, TERM_START_DATE) as PREV_EVENT_TYPE,
            LAG(EVENT_DATE, 1) over (
                        PARTITION BY REG_ID, PRODUCT_CD
                        ORDER BY EVENT_DATE, TERM_START_DATE) as PREV_EVENT_DATE,
            LEAD(EVENT_TYPE, 1, '-') over (
                        PARTITION BY REG_ID, PRODUCT_CD
                        ORDER BY EVENT_DATE, TERM_START_DATE) as NEXT_EVENT_TYPE,
            LEAD(EVENT_DATE, 1) over (
                        PARTITION BY REG_ID, PRODUCT_CD
                        ORDER BY EVENT_DATE, TERM_START_DATE) as NEXT_EVENT_DATE  
            from    mytable)TEMP
            WHERE NOT (TEMP.event_type = 'CANCELLATION' AND (TEMP.PREV_EVENT_TYPE = 'NEW SUBSCRIPTION' OR TEMP.PREV_EVENT_TYPE  = 'RENEWAL' OR 
            TEMP.PREV_EVENT_TYPE = 'UPSELL') and TEMP.EVENT_DATE <> TEMP.PREV_EVENT_DATE)
            AND 
            NOT ((TEMP.PREV_EVENT_TYPE = 'NEW SUBSCRIPTION' OR TEMP.PREV_EVENT_TYPE  = 'RENEWAL' OR 
            TEMP.PREV_EVENT_TYPE = 'UPSELL') AND TEMP.EVENT_DATE <> TEMP.NEXT_EVENT_DATE AND TEMP.NEXT_EVENT_TYPE = 'CANCELLATION')
```

Comment: why -1 for my question?. Is there any thing wrong with the question?

Comment: I suspect the lack of details,look here https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Hi Gameiswar - I am new to this forum. Can you please let me know what details were missing. As per my understanding I have clearly stated all the requirements. Please help me.

Comment: please check the link i have pasted,embrace it,you will get amazingly fast answers if you follow that link and even upvotes though the question may be basic

Comment: Can some one help me please. :(

Comment: Please respond and kindly let me know if anyone need any clarifications regarding my question..

Comment: I have added the query I am trying by editing my original post.

Comment: TheGameiswar means that in tougher SQL questions where you can't just answer with a yes or no or a hint it takes time to build the table and insert the data to develop a query and many people won't bother doing that.

Comment: Why is record 6 not modified according to rule number 2?

Comment: Hi Trincot - It needs to get modified too. Sorry I have missed that. I will update the Output data.

Comment: @beckham - trincot already posted the solution I was going to offer, so you should be set. As you see, posting the inserts helps a lot. For future questions, you may also want to include the CREATE TABLE statement (which will also show clearly the intended/existing data type of every column). Or, you can post a CREATE TABLE AS SELECT (.....) statement.   Cheers,   mathguy-ro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you got an error on your query is that before the sub-query is defined, you must indicate what you want to select from it. So if you had prefixed that with `select * from` it would have been a valid query.

Note that you don't have to do those `or` operations, as you can do that shorter with an `in` operator.

You should also negate some comparisons (as you already have `NOT`) and truncate dates with `TRUNC`.

Here is the query I would suggest:

```
SELECT      TEMP.REG_ID, 
            TEMP.EVENT_TYPE,
            TEMP.EVENT_DATE,
            TEMP.PRODUCT_CD,
            TEMP.TERM_START_DATE,
            CASE WHEN TEMP.EVENT_TYPE IN ('NEW SUBSCRIPTION', 'RENEWAL', 'UPSELL') 
                  AND TEMP.NEXT_EVENT_TYPE = 'CANCELLATION' THEN
                        LEAST(TEMP.TERM_END_DATE, TEMP.NEXT_TERM_END_DATE)
                 ELSE TEMP.TERM_END_DATE
            END AS TERM_END_DATE,
            TEMP.DAYS,
            TEMP.AMT
FROM    (SELECT     REG_ID, 
                    EVENT_TYPE,
                    EVENT_DATE,
                    PRODUCT_CD,
                    TERM_START_DATE,
                    TERM_END_DATE,
                    DAYS,
                    AMT,
                    LAG(EVENT_TYPE, 1, '-') over (
                        PARTITION BY REG_ID, PRODUCT_CD
                        ORDER BY EVENT_DATE, TERM_START_DATE) as PREV_EVENT_TYPE,
                    LAG(EVENT_DATE, 1) over (
                        PARTITION BY REG_ID, PRODUCT_CD
                        ORDER BY EVENT_DATE, TERM_START_DATE) as PREV_EVENT_DATE,
                    LEAD(EVENT_TYPE, 1, '-') over (
                        PARTITION BY REG_ID, PRODUCT_CD
                        ORDER BY EVENT_DATE, TERM_START_DATE) as NEXT_EVENT_TYPE,
                    LEAD(EVENT_DATE, 1) over (
                        PARTITION BY REG_ID, PRODUCT_CD
                        ORDER BY EVENT_DATE, TERM_START_DATE) as NEXT_EVENT_DATE,  
                    LEAD(TERM_END_DATE, 1) over (
                        PARTITION BY REG_ID, PRODUCT_CD
                        ORDER BY EVENT_DATE, TERM_START_DATE) as NEXT_TERM_END_DATE
            FROM    export_table) TEMP
WHERE   NOT (TEMP.EVENT_TYPE = 'CANCELLATION' 
             AND TEMP.PREV_EVENT_TYPE IN ('NEW SUBSCRIPTION', 'RENEWAL', 'UPSELL') 
             AND TRUNC(TEMP.EVENT_DATE) = TRUNC(TEMP.PREV_EVENT_DATE))
AND     NOT (TEMP.NEXT_EVENT_TYPE = 'CANCELLATION'
             AND TEMP.EVENT_TYPE IN ('NEW SUBSCRIPTION', 'RENEWAL', 'UPSELL') 
             AND TRUNC(TEMP.NEXT_EVENT_DATE) = TRUNC(TEMP.EVENT_DATE))
```

Note that the *term_end_date* of record 6 is also modified, as rule 2 is applicable to it.

Comment: @ Trincot, I have a new question which I have been trying from past 36 hrs. I have a query which is throwing me a error and I am unable to fix it. If you have some time can you please look?

Comment: @ Trincot - I have a new question and pretty easy one. If only you have some time. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39422688/oracle-left-outer-join-with-where-clause/39422762?noredirect=1#comment66170323_39422762

Comment: I left a comment there, as I don't see much of a problem, except for the need to swap the `-1` and `+1` in your `between` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Let me state up front that I didn't test this in Oracle as I don't have an Oracle database handy.

I pared it down to a single join, it may be useful to compare performance with the accepted answer.

```
select  
    e1.reg_id,
    e1.product_cd,
    e1.event_type, 
    e1.event_date, 
    e1.term_start_date,
    case e1.event_type when 'CANCELLATION' then e1.term_end_date else coalesce(e2.term_end_date, e1.term_end_date) end as term_end_date,
    e1.days, 
    e1.amt
from event e1 
    left outer join event e2 on 
        e1.reg_id = e2.reg_id and 
        e1.product_cd = e2.product_cd and 
        e1.term_start_date = e2.term_start_date and 
        (e1.event_type = 'CANCELLATION' or e2.event_type = 'CANCELLATION') and 
        e1.event_date <> e2.event_date  
where trunc(e1.event_date) <> trunc(e2.event_date) or e2.reg_id is null
```

Comment: @beckham, that's very surprising, it works fine on SQL server and DB2. Make sure you've got everything exactly the same, and also make sure the DATE(<timestamp>) function works in Oracle, it may be TO_DATE(<timestamp>).

Comment: @ John Kuhns, I have used the Trunc function to strip the timestamp from the Date and the query worked. :). Do you think the performance going to degrade with lot of Reg_ID's with these number of Outer joins?

Comment: Great, so now you can accept my answer. Welcome to StackExchange!

Comment: It shouldn't, depending on your indexing. I'm not an Oracle guy, but the same amount of work needs done no matter what. I don't see a better way to do this, an Oracle guru may swoop in with some magic, but I would be surprised if any other method were more efficient.

Comment: @JohnKuhns - I disagree; all those joins are not needed. Much better to use analytic functions as the OP tried in his original attempt.

Comment: I guess you'd have to show me. The rows need to be queried regardless of how it's done.