# Oracle - Left outer join with where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a join on two tables defined as a left outer join so that all records are returned from the left hand table even if they don't have a record in the right hand table. However I also need to include a where clause  but.... I still want a row from the left-hand table to be returned for each record in the left-hand table even if the condition in the where clause isn't met. Is there a way of doing this?

I am writing the query with the join condition like

```
SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.VIN = B.VIN AND 
TRUNC(a.REP_OPEN_DATE) BETWEEN TRUNC(b.CHECK_IN_DATE)+1 AND TRUNC(b.CHECK_IN_DATE)-1
```

above condition not returning any rows. where as below condition returns...

```
SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.VIN = B.VIN
```

I need the data from the left table even if the below condition doesn't met...

```
TRUNC(a.REP_OPEN_DATE) BETWEEN TRUNC(b.CHECK_IN_DATE)+1 AND TRUNC(b.CHECK_IN_DATE)-1
```

can some one please help.

A TABLE:-

```
VIN    | RO_OPEN_DATE
1234   | 04-NOV-13
6789   | 09-NOV-13
```

B TABLE

```
VIN    | CHECK_IN_DATE
1234   | 09-NOV-13
1234   | 05-NOV-13
6789   | 20-OCT-14
6789   | 29-OCT-14
```

OUTPUT SHOULD BE

```
   VIN     | RO_OPEN_DATE  | CHECK_IN_DATE
   1234    | 04-NOV-13     | 05-NOV-13
   6789    | 09-NOV-13     | NULL
```

`Condition :-For EACH RO_OPEN_DATE for a VIN, We need to check if we have +/- 1 day of CHECK_IN_DATE from RO_OPEN_DATE.`

Comment: Can you explain the objective of your requirement? I don't understand why would someone use a where clause (which is meant to filter out data) and at the same time wanting that data to appear in the result. It does not make sense at all at first glance. Can you give a precise example? table data and expected result?

Comment: Your first query looks fine. I think you are using `TRUNC(a.REP_OPEN_DATE) BETWEEN TRUNC(b.CHECK_IN_DATE)+1 AND TRUNC(b.CHECK_IN_DATE)-1` condition in `Where` clause.

Comment: I would just move the date condition out of the join and into the where clause.  Use your date condition,plus an OR clause for b.Vin is NULL.

Comment: Your title says that your query has a `where` clause.  The query you posted does not have a `where` clause.  If your query was checking the dates in a `where` clause rather than in the join condition, the query would behave as you describe.  Are you sure that the query you posted here is really the query you are running?

Comment: I looked at your question, and with the `-1` and `+1` swapped, it gives the desired output. Is this not the case for you?

Comment: @trincot - it's not giving the desired output.. Its filtering out.. May be I need to put the question in more logical way..

Comment: I don't understand, because with that change, I get exactly the two records as result, with the same column values as you specify in your question.

Comment: @trincot - I got it working. Thanks much..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your explanation does not correlate with your query. You have mentioned

"*However I also need to include a where clause but.... I still want a row from the left-hand table to be returned for each record in the left-hand table even if the condition in the where clause isn't met.*"

So I believe your query looks something like this

```
SELECT a.*, 
       b.* 
FROM   a 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN b 
                    ON a.vin = b.vin 
WHERE  Trunc(a.rep_open_date) BETWEEN Trunc(b.check_in_date) + 1 AND 
                                      Trunc(b.check_in_date) - 1
```

In the above the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will be converted into `INNER JOIN` due to the filtration of right table in `Where` clause

So as you have used in first query the right table filters should be part of `JOIN` condition, Which will return rows from LEFT table even though there is no matching records in RIGHT side table.

```
SELECT a.*, 
       b.* 
FROM   a 
       left outer join b 
                    ON a.vin = b.vin 
                       AND Trunc(a.rep_open_date) BETWEEN 
                           Trunc(b.check_in_date) + 1 AND 
                           Trunc(b.check_in_date) - 1
```

**Update :**

You have used between operator like `10 between 11 and 9`  but it should be `10 between 9 and 11`

```
SELECT a.*, 
       b.* 
FROM   a 
       left outer join b 
                    ON a.vin = b.vin 
                       AND CAST(a.rep_open_date as date) BETWEEN 
                           CAST(b.check_in_date as date) - 1 AND 
                           CAST(b.check_in_date as date) + 1
```

Comment: @prdr - that doesn't worked too... my estimate is 10 between 11 and 9 is same as 10 between 9 and 11??

Comment: @beckham - Sql `Between` operator works this way **value between smaller value and larger value**. So you have to use this way only `10 between 9 and 11`

Comment: @beckham - I tested your sample data with `SQL Server` it is working fine. SQLFIDDLE.COM is not working will show you a demo. Am not good in Oracle so removed `TRUNC` and used `CAST` to remove the time part. Please check now

Answer (score 0):

If there are no rows in B that satisfy the join, then you'll have to specify what to do with NULL values for b.CHECK_IN_DATE, e.g.,

```
TRUNC(a.REP_OPEN_DATE) BETWEEN TRUNC(NVL(b.CHECK_IN_DATE,a.rep_open_date))+1 AND TRUNC(NVL(b.CHECK_IN_DATE,a.rep_open_date))-1
```

You need to decide what to do when b.CHECK_IN_DATE is NULL, which will happen whenever you have no records in B that satisfy the join condition, because a.REP_OPEN_DATE will never be between two NULLs.  I used a.rep_open_date as an example that will always succeed.  You could also simply add an OR b.checkin_date_date IS NULL to your WHERE clause.